# App exits on its own if certain permissions are denied. Any way to prevent?

Tags: applications, permissions, privacy

Some jerk apps, if certain permissions are denied to them, exits on its own. This forced the user to grant permission to use, which contradicts with appops' intention.

Is there a way to prevent such apps from accessing real data without letting them quit automatically?

I know XPrivacy is a good Xposed module, but it doesn't run on Android 7